# Virtual Machine Information

Tags: virtualbox

I am new to Linux and need some information. I have download the latest version of Ubuntu 64-bit from website. I want to run it in Virtual Machine, is this work i mean Virtual Machine run the ISO file or is there other file for Virtual Machine, because once i used the OSGEO live and it's completely different.

Comment: The .iso file is an DVD image. You set the .iso for the DVD drive of the virtualbox, and boot from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your objective ? It is not clear to me. Anyway if you want to install Ubuntu 64 bit OS in your VM with the ISO file, this is doable. You have to mount the iso file in the virtual CD drive and start the VM. What is the hypervisor you are using? I mean, is it VirtualBox, KVM or something else ? If you want to know something else, just let me know.

Comment: My objective is simply to use Ubuntu through VirtualBox. Help me steps by steps, if you can...Thank for help...

Comment: USe the link below to see how to create a VM from the scratch from ISO file. First you create a VM, just like a physical machine. then you boot the VM with ISO. You have to do it as shown in the images here.   http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox

Comment: Got to new in to top of the panel. It will open a window, asking you put the VM name, and OS type and version (32bit or 64 bit). Then go next page where you are asked to put the RAM of your VM. Make sure it is less than your PC RAM. then go next,"Create a virtual Hard drive now", put "VDI", then You can try "Fixed size" in next window. Put the size of your hard drive. Then you are done with your VM.

Comment: After that you can install the OS using your ISO, by going to settings, then storage - > IDE Controller -> browse ISO.. You can understand that using the images shown in the previous link.

Answer (score 0):

Ahsan,

The ISO file is sufficient for what I believe you are asking.  If you simply want to run Ubuntu in a VM you are on the right path and can use the ISO you have downloaded.  What I have done in the past is created a folder in my home directory and named it "ISO Images" and then moved the ISO from "Downloads" folder to the newly created "ISO Images" folder.  I have then opened the VM and during the set-up process, pointed the VM at the new folder and the desired iso image.

Hope this helps and good luck!